# Тестирование POST запроса в ruby

Tags: post, ruby, sinatra

Как правильно написать этот тест, используя фикстуры?

```
def test_entity_create
  post '/users', "#{users(:user_one).name}"
  assert last_response.ok?, last_response.inspect

  response_body = last_response.body
  real_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = #{users(:user_one).name}")

  result = parse_response_json(response_body)
  check_data(result, real_result)
end
```

При запуске выдает:

> Error: ApiTest#test_entity_create: RuntimeError: unsupported: NilClass
>   /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@sinatra_test/gems/arel-
>   6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:729:in `unsupported' ... test/api_test.rb:34:in`test_entity_create'

Answer (score 1):

```
def test_entity_create
  assert_difference('User.count') do
   post :create, params: { user: { name: users(:user_one).name } }
  end

  assert_redirected_to users_path
end
```